# Error Creating Controller in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I repeatedly get this error whenever I create a Controller in ASP.NET MVC 4. I don't have an idea why this error appeared. Anyone help me please.

[image]

Comment: @AdamPedley do you have any idea about this error Sir?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the cause of the error, all I could suggest is a reinstall of Visual Studio at this point.